# If $a \cdot x = b \cdot x$ for any vector $x$, where "$\cdot$" is the dot product, then $a=b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Show that if $a \cdot x = b \cdot x$ for any vector $x$, where "$\cdot$" is the dot product, then $a=b$.

This seems so simple and obvious that if $a \cdot x = b \cdot x$ then dividing both sides by $x$ will show $a = b$, but I know vector geometry is never that simple.

I would like a little bit of a hint or a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: You are correct to think that it is not that simple. The dot product is ~not~ multiplication, so dividing does not cancel.

Comment: And by the way, are $a,b,x$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Hint:  the problem is equivalent to asking if $\vec v\cdot \vec w=0$ for all vectors $\vec w$ implies that $\vec v=\vec 0$.

Comment: Put $x=a-b$. Then $a\cdot x=b\cdot x$ implies $0=(a-b)\cdot x=(a-b)\cdot (a-b)=\|a-b\|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ $$a \cdot x=b\cdot x \quad \Rightarrow \quad (a-b) \cdot x = 0 \quad \text{for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$}. $$

Since it must hold for all $x$, we can choose a particular $x$ that gives us what we want. Look at the defining properties of the dot product (really it holds for any inner product) and choose the appropriate $x$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $a:=\langle a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\rangle$ and the same idea is applied for vectors $b, x$.

This leaves: $a_1\cdot x_1+a_2\cdot x_2+\dots+a_n\cdot x_n = b_1\cdot x_1+b_2\cdot x_2+\dots+b_n\cdot x_n$

This implies that $x_1(a_1-b_1)+x_2(a_2-b_2)+\cdots+x_n(a_n-b_n)=0$

While $a=b$ does satisfy the above equation, there are other solutions.

Consider $x =\langle1,1\rangle, a= \langle2,2\rangle,$ and $b = \langle4,0\rangle$.
You end up with $2\cdot1+2\cdot1 = 4 \cdot 1 + 0\cdot1$ and $a$ does not equal $b$.

Comment: In English "any" is ambiguous. It can mean "some", but it can also mean "all" or "an arbitrary". Since the question is asking to show that the statement is true, the statement that is true is with "all $x$".

Comment: @plop I can definitely see that interpretation of the question. Thats why math has $\exists$ and $\forall$